# Entity Framework “Update model from Database, table becomes relation

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I'm trying to create a table from within visual studio and update my .edmx file inside Visual Studio by right-clicking the file and selecting Update Model from Database.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableName] (
[UserId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[CategoryId]   INT         NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_responsibleUser] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([UserId], [pkID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_responsibleUser_user] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([UserId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_categoryResponsibleUser_category] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[categories] ([CategoryId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This table contains two foreign keys to the tables i want to link. After I run the script "Update Model from Database", a relation between the two tables pops up.

**Now Heres the problem:** I need EF to generate an instance of my class in Visual studio like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<tableName> TableIWantToBeGeneratedByEF { get; set; }
```

As I said, with the current mapping it just creates a relation between two tables. How do I alter my query when creating the table for this to happen? Can this be achieved while using two foreign keys as the primary key or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost forgot. It seems that it was the  [compound primary keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) that caused the problem. I changed so both my foreign keys just acted like foreign keys and not as a combined primary key, then created a columnn named Id instead with datatype INT Identity. 
Ran the script "Update Model from Database" in .edmx designer and boom, there it was.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the model designed, select all (ctrl + A), press 'delete' button to delete them, and finally right click and select Update Model from Database. This will force EF to re-generate all model.

(Or just delete all referenced tables so that they are also regenerated)

Comment: Doesnt work, the table still shows up as a relationship, not a table.